# Generate a file by PHP

Tags: php, apache, nginx, file-upload, file-permissions

I want to generate a file by `batch.php`, which is linked to the button in [this page](http://www.matrixandcompany.com):

```
<?php
  echo "Hello world!";
  'cat 123 > uploads/cat.txt';
  echo "Bye world!";
?>
```

Clicking on the button does launch `batch.php`, however, `cat.txt` is NOT generated on the server side.

Does anyone know how to fix this? Maybe I need to setup some permission for the folder?

**Edit 1**:

`ps aux|grep -E 'apache|www-data|http|php'` returns:

```
root     12269  0.0  2.1 278256 10796 ?        Ss   Aug02   3:38 php-fpm: master process (/etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf)                    
www-data 12301  0.0  0.8  97728  4044 ?        S    Aug02   3:27 nginx: worker process
www-data 12302  0.0  0.8  98104  4296 ?        S    Aug02   3:54 nginx: worker process
www-data 12303  0.0  0.9  97940  4520 ?        S    Aug02   3:46 nginx: worker process
www-data 12304  0.0  0.9  98132  4544 ?        S    Aug02   3:47 nginx: worker process
timur    14888  0.0  0.1  11712   932 pts/0    S+   15:04   0:00 grep --color=auto -E apache|www-data|http|php
www-data 18748  0.0  8.7 298196 43668 ?        S    Sep07   0:12 php-fpm: pool www                                                       
www-data 18749  0.0  6.4 286660 32432 ?        S    Sep07   0:11 php-fpm: pool www                                                       
www-data 21100  0.0  8.3 296204 42048 ?        S    Sep05   1:02 php-fpm: pool www
```

`ls -l` returns:

```
total 20
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root       84 Sep 12 08:33 batch.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 timur    timur    5120 Sep 12 09:00 generateFile.exe
-rw-rw-r-- 1 timur    timur     138 Sep 12 08:28 index.html
drwxrwxrwx 2 timur    timur    4096 Sep 12 15:03 uploads
```

I granted `777` to `uploads`, and I tried all the possible owner names and owner groups (ie, `timur:timur`, `www-data:www-data` and `root:root`), but none of them works...

Comment: Does your website have write permissions to the folder where generateFile is?

Comment: Yes, this is what I guess too... so where could I modify these permissions?

Comment: I have no idea, I can't see your folder structure or where you put generateFile.exe.

Comment: `index.html`, `batch.php` and `generateFile.exe` are all in the same folder `/var/www/matrixandcompany.com/html`.

Comment: What access do you have to the server? SSH, FTP? Assuming at least FTP check the chmod of the folder and the files, for testing purposes set them to 777 (though don't leave it at this forever). You may get away with 774 or even 744.

Comment: I have the entire access to the server...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is to write `exec('cat 123 > uploads/cat.txt')` or `shell_exec('cat 123 > uploads/cat.txt')` instead of `'cat 123 > uploads/cat.txt'`.

Then, although `drwxrwxrwx 2 timur    timur    4096 Sep 12 15:03 uploads` works, assigning `755` and `www-data:www-data` (reserved to PhP) to `uploads` is more correct.